# Call PyObject_CallObject with more than one function argument

Tags: python, c++

If I have a function in Python like this:

```
def multiply(a, b)
    return a * b
```

How can I call `PyObject_CallObject` when it will give me an error if I have more than two arguments? There may be a much better way of calling a function from C++ but I am very new to the Python/C API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_callobject#c.PyObject_CallObject):

> **`PyObject* PyObject_CallObject(PyObject *callable_object, PyObject *args)`**
>
> <sup>Return value: New reference.</sup>
>
> Call a callable Python object `callable_object`, with **arguments given
>   by the tuple `args`**. If no arguments are needed, then `args` may be `NULL`.
>   Returns the result of the call on success, or `NULL` on failure. **This is
>   the equivalent of the Python expression `callable_object(*args)`**.

In other words:

- You can pass more than one argument to the function by passing a single `tuple` containing the arguments. So you'd have to build a `tuple` containing `x` and `y` (i.e. `(x, y)`) and then pass the tuple as single parameter to `PyObject_CallObject(multiply, the_tuple)` this will be equivalent to `multiply(x, y)`.
- It does *not* represent the most general call. The most generic call is [`PyObject_Call`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_callobject#c.PyObject_Call) which takes two arguments: a tuple of positional arguments and a dictionary of keyword arguments.
- There are also the [`PyObject_CallFunction*`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_callobject#c.PyObject_CallFunction) functions that are similar to `PyObject_CallObject` but they avoid having to create the tuple and allow multiple parameters.

Comment: Thank you! `PyObject_CallFunction` appears to be better for what I'm doing so I'll use that instead.